# Expand list of dates by incrementing dates by one day in python

Tags: python, list, date

In Python I have a list of dates as strings:

```
dates = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-21']
```

I would like to increment these dates by one day and add them to this list, like so:

```
dates_new = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-21', '2022-01-22']
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: These are _strings_, not dates. As you've probably already identified, you will need to _parse_ these strings to create a `datetime.datetime` object, _add_ a day, and then _format_ them back to strings. What part of this problem are you stuck on? Each of these has individually already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow. Asking a _specific_ question allows us to direct you to the answer to your actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

one_day = timedelta(days=1)
dates = ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-21"]

out = []
for d in dates:
    x = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")
    out.append(d)
    out.append((x + one_day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-21', '2022-01-22']
```

Comment: Give some explanation about the code, or everyone will only copy the code and use it

Answer (score 3):

You will need to import a library:

```
import datetime
```

First convert the strings to dates using `datetime.strptime`.
The important part of the code is the `datetime.timedelta`, is a function to sum days, month or years to a date.
Create a new list to store the dates + 1, and then alternate the old date with the new date, that was calculated.

```
dates = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-21']
newDates = []

for date in dates:
    tempDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    tempDate = tempDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    tempDate = tempDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    newDates.append(date)
    newDates.append(tempDate)

print(newDates)
```

Result:

```
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-21', '2022-01-22']
```

Comment: OP wants the dates to be interleaved, so you might as well add them all to an output list in the `for date in dates` loop, as shown by [Andrej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75164829/843953)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice, I will fix it

Answer (score 1):

With [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) class to get the needed difference/offset in *days*:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import chain

dates = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-21']
dates_inc = list(chain.from_iterable((d, str((timedelta(days=1) + datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")).date())) 
                                     for d in dates))
print(dates_inc)
```

---

```
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-21', '2022-01-22']
```

Comment: You aren't _just_ using `datetime.timedelta` (which is not a function, btw). An explanation of all the other things you do (which make up most of the solution) would make your answer much better.